# union some two-field tables into one multi-field with first field as key

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Here is ugly implementation:

```
select [keyfield]
     , (MAX([f1])) as f1
     , (MAX([f2])) as f2
     , (MAX([f3])) as f3
     , (MAX([f4])) as f4
     , (MAX([f5])) as f5

from (
    select [keyfield]
         , [f1]
         , Null as f2
         , Null as f3
         , Null as f4
         , Null as f5
    from t1

    UNION ALL

    select [keyfield]
         , Null as f1
         , [f2]
         , Null as f3
         , Null as f4
         , Null as f5
    from t2

    UNION ALL

    ...
    ) subquery
    group by subquery.[keyfield]
```

Is there other way of doing the same?

Comment: First of all, what would you like to do? Do you have six table?

Comment: @PeterRing yes I have FIVE 2-field tables and want to get one 6-field

Comment: Okay, so: Can you discribe the tables, properties and so, what connection they have and what wuld you like to have for a solution?

Comment: @PeterRing first field of all tables is keyfield which I use to group them all together. (btw corrected - there are 5 tables)

Comment: maybe use a view for all these tables from the inner query?

Comment: @MilenPavlov sorry, I don't understand what do you mean. The major pain in current realization is adding new field.

Comment: Do all the tables contain the same data in "keyfield" - with other words if there is a keyfiled = "1" would all 5 tables contain an entry for "1"?

Comment: can you join all these tables on the `[keyfield]`? like `select t1.keyfield, t1.f1 as f1, t2.f2 as f2 from t1 inner join t2 on t1.keyfield = t2.keyfield` ... and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve your problem with joins.:

```
select [keyfield]
     , (MAX([t1.f1])) as f1
     , (MAX([t2.f2])) as f2
     , (MAX([t3.f3])) as f3
     , (MAX([t4.f4])) as f4
     , (MAX([t5.f5])) as f5

from t1
Join t2 on t2.keyfield = t1.keyfield
Join t3 on t3.keyfield = t1.keyfield
Join t4 on t4.keyfield = t1.keyfield
Join t5 on t5.keyfield = t1.keyfield
Group by t1.keyfield
```

Comment: This only works if every table has at least one row, of course (hopefully it works, though).  Ideally, the multiplicities would be 1:1 too, so you don't need the `GROUP BY` and aggregates either.